# Counting most occurrences of a field's value

Tags: mysql, count, field, sum

Given the following query, how do I return the p_name with the most transactions? And similarly, how do I return the t_amount with the most transactions. I'd like to do it all in this one query of course.

```
SELECT t.*, p.* 
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN partners p ON p.id=t.partner_id
```

which can return something like:

```
t_amount     t_platform      t_user     p_id      p_name

100.00       windows         122         20       simmons
200.00       windows         211         20       simmons
100.00       mac             200         18       smith
100.00       linux           190         20       simmons
100.00       mac             100         18       smith
```

So given that result set, I'd get back best_partner = simmons  and also best_amount = 100.00

Thanks!

Comment: best meaning most_frequent. So, the best_amount is 100 (the most frequent occurrence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume "best partner"= the parner with the highest number of transactions and "best amount" = the most frequently occurring transaction amount.

To count the transactions you can use the Count() function and group by. Something like this:

```
SELECT p.name,count(t.id) as transactionCount
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN partners p ON p.id=t.partner_id
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Similar for "best amount":

```
SELECT t.amount, Count(t.id) as transactionAmountCount
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN partners p ON p.id=t.partner_id
GROUP BY t.amount
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: Combined as two sub queries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT p.name
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN partners p ON p.id=t.partner_id
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY count(t.id) DESC 
LIMIT 1) as best_partner
,
(SELECT t.amount
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN partners p ON p.id=t.partner_id
GROUP BY t.amount
ORDER BY Count(t.id) DESC 
LIMIT 1) as most_occuring_transaction_amount
```

Comment: No way to combine the 2 queries?

Comment: SELECT t.amount,p.name, Count(t.id) as transactionAmountCount
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN partners p ON p.id=t.partner_id
GROUP BY t.amount,p.name
ORDER BY 3 DESC 
LIMIT 1

Comment: @remi, what does the ORDER BY 3 do? More directly, what is the 3 referring to?

Comment: @k00k (myself), 3 refers to the 3rd column.

Comment: @k00k: I don't think you can do this in one single query, but you can avoid the roundtrip to the database by running two sub queries. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @remi: Your query will give the partner with the highest number of any transaction amount, but there may be an amount occurring more frequently distributed over transactions for different partners.